# Unable to calculate pixel difference with opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I am forced to calculate pixel difference pixel by pixel between frames of a video.
I initialize the pixeldifference variable to 0. (assumeall the frames are valid frames in the video)
The problem is lastFrame and frame are always identical which means the code with the cout statement "Pixel count incremented" is never triggered. I know a couple of frames can be identical but i never see that output statement even once. Which leads me to believe the two frames are identical always. Should i do something else? I'd appreciate any guidance. I'm very new to opencv (excus a little bad coding practice inside it was for debugging purposes)

```
Mat lastFrame;
Mat frame;
capture.read(lastFrame);
capture.read(frame);

while(counter<tofind)
{
for(int cur_row=0_PX;cur_row<max_PX;cur_row++)
{
            for(int cur_cols=0;cur_cols<frame.cols;cur_cols++)
            {
                    Vec3b pixels_currentFrame = frame.at<cv::Vec3b>(cur_row, cur_cols);
                    Vec3b pixels_lastFrame = lastFrame.at<cv::Vec3b>(cur_row, cur_cols);
                    bCur=int(pixels_currentFrame.val[0]);
                    gCur=int(pixels_currentFrame.val[1]);
                    rCur=int(pixels_currentFrame.val[2]);
                    bPrev=int(pixels_lastFrame.val[0]);
                    gPrev=int(pixels_lastFrame.val[1]);
                    rPrev=int(pixels_lastFrame.val[2]);
                    bDiff=abs(bCur-bPrev);
                    gDiff=abs(gCur-gPrev);
                    rDiff=abs(rCur-rPrev);
                    if (abs(bCur-bPrev) > checkval ||
                        abs(rCur-rPrev) > checkval ||
                        abs(gCur-gPrev) > checkval)
                    {
                            pixeldifference++;
                            cout<<"Pixel count incremented"<<endl;
                    }
            }

}
lastFrame=frame;
capture.read(frame);
/*
    some other stuff happens here
*/
counter++;
}
```

Comment: What the value of `checkval` ?

Comment: 70 and it's a predetermined number

Comment: And the min/max values of `pixels_currentFrame.val[x]` ?